# How to access @PathVariable in a Spring MVC exception handler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it valid to do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Post doSomething(@PathVariable postId) {

}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
private ModelAndView handleException(Exception ex, @PathVariable postId) {

}
```

Looks like Spring is ignoring my exception handler when I add an `@PathVariable` to its method signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO that kind of information should be contained within the exception itself anyway.

I'm not aware that exception handlers get path variables.

Answer (score 0):

@PathVariable is not supported indeed in @ExceptionHandler methods. In Spring 3.1 however you should be able to configure an ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver with a PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver and that should make it work. Feel free to open a ticket in [JIRA](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR), seems like something we could add.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this? (A method in controller)

```
private Optional<String> getPathVariable(String paramName) {
   return Optional.ofNullable((Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE))
         .filter(map -> map.containsKey(paramName))
         .map(map -> map.get(paramName));
}
```